# Type annotations for Enum attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, type-hinting, python-typing

I have this piece of code:

```
import enum


class Color(enum.Enum):
    RED = '1'
    BLUE = '2'
    GREEN = '3'


def get_color_return_something(some_color):
    pass
```

How do I properly add type annotations to the `some_color` variable in this function, if I suppose that I'll receive an enum attribute from the Color enum (for example: `Color.RED`)?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Type hinting the Color class should work:

```
def get_color_return_something(some_color: Color):
    print(some_color.value)
```

Comment: If I pass `Color.RED` to this function, I get the warning "Expected type 'Color', got 'str' instead".

Comment: I can't reproduce this warning. In my Python console I get `>>> get_color_return_something(Color.RED)
1`. No warning so far.

Comment: @Gazzini This plugin may help with the warning. https://pypi.org/project/pylint-enums/

Comment: If you use this syntax for type hinting, for clarity/readability of your code it's probably good to have these enum classes in a separate module/folder called "types" or something similar.

Comment: @Gazzini I don't see that locally, and this online mypy checker also doesn't show it: [link](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=67656249f1527463378d6c7756a9a8f1)

Comment: @Gazzini If I literally pass in the string `"1"` rather than `Color.RED`, I do get the same error as you, so perhaps that's what happened there? i.e. `get_color_return_something("1")` is incorrect, `get_color_return_something(Color.RED)` is correct

Answer (score 21):

You can try to use an option with type hint Literal.

From [official PEP8 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) we know that:

> Literal it's type that can be used to indicate to type checkers that the corresponding variable or function parameter has a value equivalent to the provided literal (or one of several literals)

So in case if you need to use some specific values for a function argument it will be one of the best options. But this approach will not work fully as we expected, because of the type of the Enum values. Each value will have a type of Enum class. This means that for the code example below we will be able to put Color.GREEN as the function argument. So such a solution will be just information for developers, but not a mandatory rule for a function  argument.

```
class Color(enum.Enum):
    RED = '1'
    BLUE = '2'
    GREEN = '3'

print(type(Color.RED)  # will return <enum 'Color'>
```

Code example:

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import Literal


class Color(Enum):
    RED = '1'
    BLUE = '2'
    GREEN = '3'

def some_function(some_color: Literal[Color.RED, Color.BLUE]) -> None:
    pass
```

The second option it's fully correct solution provided by @ibarrond from the [post above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52624948/5460460) with just a class type hint.

```
some_color: Color
```

So here you can choose the option to work with depending on your needs.

From my point of view we can try to specify possible Enum values for developers, to be more clear in our requirements for a function.

Answer (score 7):

```
def get_color_return_something(some_color: Color):
    pass
```

Answer (score 4):

The following will work with Pyton 3.9/PyCharm

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import Optional, Union


class Color(Enum):
    RED: int = 1
    GREEN: int = 2


def guess_color(x: Union[Color.RED, Color.GREEN]) -> Optional[ValueError]:
    if x == Color.RED:
        print("Gotcha!")
    else:
        return ValueError(f"It's not {Color.RED}")


guess_color(Color.RED)
```

Comment: Why returning the `ValueError` instead of raising it? Also, this function will fail mypy check. See this [gist on mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=0705e6414e3a9bcac4a60170f4c6c168).

Comment: @Georgy: I didn't really give much thought to returning a `ValueError`, but it is not relevant for what I'm trying to show. Replace the line with a print statement if you prefer. Also, I have no experience with mypy, so I can't help you with that, sorry. I explicitly stated that it works with Python 3.0/PyCharm, I'm not claiming anything more than that.

Comment: You can use `Literal[Color.RED]` from typing to get this to work correctly. I tried to suggest an edit, but it looks like the queue is full. (you will also need to return `None` in the if condition)

Comment: This answer helped me because it shows that I can type the class attributes similar to a `dataclass`.

Comment: This really defeats the purpose of the enum

Comment: You can use `Color` as a type hint for both the parameters and the result of the function if needed (eg. `def guess_color(x: Color) -> Color:`). Repeating the values of the enum in each function you're writing doesn't look like a good idea. (Also, even if it is unrelated to the question, returning an exception instead of raising it is really uncommon and not what you typically want to do in Python).

Answer (score 4):

Another *strange* syntactic workaround is to specify Enum members as the type of the Enum class using the forward-referencing syntax of quoting (per [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references)):

```
from enum import Enum


class ETest(Enum):
    EXAMPLE: 'ETest' = "example"  <--- forward referenced type


def example() -> ETest:
    return ETest.EXAMPLE


print(type(ETest.EXAMPLE.value))

<class 'str'>
```

In the image below it's evident that the warnings highlighted in PyCharm are no longer present.

[image: type-hint with reference to Enum class]

For reference, here is a screenshot of PyCharm's grievance with specifying the `EXAMPLE` member as a `<str>` type as makes sense:

[image: PyCharm pylint warning Enum Typing]

I am not a fan or this approach but it *does* get rid of the warning.

Comment: I was looking for some documentation like this, so weird. Is this a newer behavior? I can't remember this being an issue with Enum back with Python 3.5.

Comment: TBH I don't know. I only recently started making use of Python Enums and can't say when the issue might have arisen.