# Python 3 type hint for string options

Tags: python, type-hinting

Let's say, I have a function with a string argument corresponding for a method name:

```
def func(method: str):
    if method not in ('simple_method', 'some_other_method'):
        raise ValueError('Unknown method')
```

Can I add all the possible supported options (strings) as a type hint for this argument? For instance, something like this (which doesn't work since there is no Str in typing):

```
from typing import Str

def func(method: Str['simple_method', 'some_other_method']):
    ...
```

Comment: It seems that your possible method names are an `enum`, so you could look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624736/python-type-annotations-for-enum-value

Comment: `typing.Literal` this would allow you to specify `def func(method: Literal['simple_method', 'some_other_method']): ...` you can get it like so

`from typing import Literal`

Answer (score 77, accepted):

## Option 1: `Literal`

You can do that with [literal types](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/literal_types.html).

```py
from typing import Literal
# from typing_extensions import Literal # Python 3.7 or below

def func(method: Literal['simple_method', 'some_other_method']):
    ...
```

### Python 3.8

Thanks to the [PEP 586](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586/), the `Literal` is [already included](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) by default in the Python 3.8 `typing` module.

## Option 2: `Enum`

If you'd rather not use type hints, you could also consider [enums](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) like so:

```py
from enum import Enum
class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3
```

Once you have an enum with all the possible choices, you can hint the function in order to accept only your custom enum. More info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

Example:

```py
from typing import NewType

Colors = NewType('Colors', Color)
```

Comment: As someone who uses both hinting and enums, enums can be overkill for a simple option to a single function.

Comment: As someone who uses both hinting and enums, how is it overkill? It's a feature of the language, why would it be "overkill" to use it?

Comment: `Literal` is not always suitable. For example, if a function takes an argument defined as `Literal`, only a literal string like "red" is allowed to be passed, but not a variable that holds value "red". Hence the name – "literal"