# Type expression describing the string literal union of Enum names?

Tags: python, enums, python-typing

Given:

```py
class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3
```

Is there a type expression `Foo` such that:

```py
Foo[Color] = Literal["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type annotations for Enum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624736/type-annotations-for-enum-value)

Comment: Your `Foo` expression seems like a dictionary, having the enum as key and the literal as value...You don't show how `Foo` is initially declared, so we're left guessing from syntax what exactly it may be.

Answer (score 7):

From PEP 586 -- Literal Types

> [*Legal parameters for Literal at type check time*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586/#legal-parameters-for-literal-at-type-check-time)
>
> Literal[Color.RED]  # Assuming Color is some enum

Also in PEP 586:

> [*Literals, enums, and forward references*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586/#literals-enums-and-forward-references)
>
> - `Literal["Color.RED"]` (...) In cases like these, we always assume the user meant to construct a literal string.
> - `"Literal[Color.RED]"` (...)  If the user wants a forward reference, they must wrap the entire literal type in a string

```py
from typing import Literal
from enum import Enum


class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3


FIRST = Literal["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE"]
SECOND = Literal[Color.RED, Color.GREEN]
THIRD = Literal["Color.RED", "Color.GREEN"]


def one(arg: FIRST):
    print("FIRST")


def two(arg: SECOND):
    print("SECOND")


def three(arg: THIRD):
    print("THIRD")


one("GREEN")  # Linter issues no warning
one(Color.RED)  # Expected type 'Literal["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE"]', got 'Color' instead
one(Color.RED.name)  # Expected type 'Literal["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE"]', got 'str' instead 

two("RED")  # Expected type 'Color', got 'str' instead 
two(Color.RED)  # Linter issues no warning

three("RED")  # Expected type 'Literal["Color.RED", "Color.GREEN"]', got 'Literal["RED"]' instead 
three("Color.RED") # Linter issues no warning
three(Color.RED.name)  # Expected type 'Literal["Color.RED", "Color.GREEN"]', got 'str' instead
```

If you want to declare the `Literal` by passing as argument a collection of Enum members I think that isn't possible (see: [*Illegal parameters for Literal at type check time*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586/#illegal-parameters-for-literal-at-type-check-time)) the static type checker gives the following warning:

> 'Literal' may be parameterized with literal ints, byte and unicode strings, bools, Enum values, None, other literal types, or type aliases to other literal types

> Can't use starred expression here

```py
teste_one = ("RED", "GREEN", "BLUE")
FIRST = Literal[teste_one]
FIRST = Literal[*teste_one]

test_two = Color.__members__.keys()
SECOND = Literal[test_two]
SECOND = Literal[*test_two]
```

You'll always have to declare the arguments to `Literal[...]` explicitly.

Answer (score -3):

You could use Enum [name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes) programmatic access for a similar effect like :

```
class Colors(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3
   

ColorsNames = [color.name for color in Colors]

print(ColorsNames)

['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE']
```

Comment: This is useless for static typing, though.