# Python typing: How to check list items are enum values

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Say I have some enum:

```
class ExampleEnum(Enum):
     FOO = "FOO"
     BAR = "BAR"
     ....
     FOOBAR = "FOOBAR"
```

I want to add some type checking to a list to say that the elements must be values from ExampleEnum, i.e something like:

`myList: list[Literal[ExampleEnum]] = ...`

How can this be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68758590/15981783

Comment: type checking or type hinting?

Comment: It isn't clear what you expect. As alluded to above, type hinting is not the same thing as type checking. Type hints are not enforced at runtime (unless you write code that does that, or use a library that does that). Also, what exactly do you mean? Do you mean `ExampleEnum.foo` or `"FOO"`?

Comment: What's the intended right-hand side? If you're looking for e.g. `myList = ["FOO", "BAR"]`, then note that the point of an enum is _not_ to use the literal values.